# How to query a Many to Many elements using JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I would like to query my ManyToMany relationship finding by the parent entity ID.

Having one User, I expect to recieve all the Post which my user has tagged as Favourite.
I have two entities, `UserEntity` and `PostEntity`, and one joinTable, `user_post_favourite`.

```
@Entity
class UserEntity {@Column
String name;

@OneToMany(cascade = { 
            CascadeType.PERSIST, 
            CascadeType.MERGE })
@JoinTable(name = "user_post_favourite", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), 
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
"post_id"))
private List<PostEntity> postFavourites;
}
```

And my repo:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long> {
    List<PostEntity> findAllPostFavourites_PostId(Long id);
}
```

With the native query above does not work. Unsure if it should work like that.
Of course I can define a particular service and repo to access the join table but I would like to avoid it if it possible.

Comment: Where is PostEntity in your code? Is this RestaurantEntity?

Comment: I have fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it is a ManyToMany relationship

Answer (score 0):

Just create a simple query:

```
Select p from User u join u.postFavourites p where u.Id = :userId;
```